# Redirect(?) from one pdf, copy/pasted into URL bar, to a completely different pdf?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, redirect

**Short version**: If someone were to copy/paste a PDF URL into a web browser (ex: http://domain.com/pdfs/test.pdf), Is there a way to get it to automatically redirect to a completely different pdf on the same server (ex: http://domain.com/pdfs/alt/difTest.pdf), preferrably without them even seeing the copy/pasted version? This an ASP.net environment. Thanks.

**Long version**: Please forgive me, this is probably an easy solution but I can't seem to pinpoint one. I think it has something to do with 301 redirects (something I know nothing about), but as near as I can tell that all has to do with SEO. I tried using an .htaccess but that's specific to Linux.

I've been doing site updates for a medical website that's been built in an asp.net environment. I don't know asp that well and most of the stuff I've been doing is usually HTML. Anyway, Because this is a medical website, things have to go through certain channels and approval processes take time, so let me assure, what they're asking me to do is what needs to be done, lest they be subject to another 60 day approval process, so please don't ask me why I'm doing it this way. In the reading I've done over the last few days I've come across many different variations of what might be the solution, but it's usually slightly different variations of the same problem, but in different environments and under different criteria.

From here, refer to the short version. Thanks all. I hope you can set me straight on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this code in your Gloabal.asax file:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object start, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.FilePath == "//pdfs/test.pdf")
    {
        Response.RedirectPermanent("~/pdfs/alt/difTest.pdf");
    }
}
```

Note: If you are using an earlier version than 4.0 you may need to substitute

`Response.RedirectPermanent("~/pdfs/alt/difTest.pdf");`

with

```
Response.StatusCode = 301;
Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently";
Response.RedirectLocation = "~/pdfs/alt/difTest.pdf";
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've gone through the entire site and there is no global.asax file that I can find, unfortunately. Is this something that's supposed to be mandatory within an asp.net site? As I said, this is an older site that was not built by me and I've just been doing content updates for the majority. The site is still built in tables, afterall, to give you an idea of just how...outdates (we'll say)... we're talking.

Comment: This might just be all asp, and not necessarily .net. The aspnet_client folder this has is empty, so the best I can tell you is that rather than .html files, these are all .asp files. I hope that makes it clear. Personally, i'm still not sure.